# What's the easiest way to send a string to another application? (Win API)

Tags: c, winapi, api, ipc

I have two Win32 API programs written in plain C: Program A and program B. I want program B to send the string "Hello World" to program A. So B needs to do the following:

1) Detect if program A is running.

2) If it is, send "Hello World" string to A.

3) If A is not running, B should show an error message.

Can someone point me to the API functions necessary to do this? How would I establish such a communication between two programs? I think the biggest problem is that the "Hello World" string is in the address space of program B and it somehow needs to move to the address space of A. So just passing a memory pointer is not sufficient... I need a different approach. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at [Interprocess Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the other program's main window I recommend using [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Which one you use depends on just what you know about the other process.

Once you have that the easiest way to send text data is via a [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28VS.85%29.aspx) windows message.

To show an error message, use [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Google for `WM_COPYDATA`.  Failing that, you could use a UDP message over the local IP stack or a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might be helpful:
http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/10/605.aspx

It even has a downloadable sample program.