# Open file in running instance of application in Windows (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I have a C++ (pure win32, no MFC) application that registers a file type to open with the executable. However, I want it to open inside of the running application if it is already running. What is a good way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243953 then [What's the easiest way to send a string to another application? (Win API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329272/whats-the-easiest-way-to-send-a-string-to-another-application-win-api)